# c++ compile-time assertion

Tags: c++, boost, assertions

I'm using a macro that might be dangerous:

```
#define REMAINDER(v, size) ((v) & (size -1))
```

obviously it assumes that size is a power of 2.

I would like to make sure size is indeed a power of 2, but at compile time. (testing at run time is easy, but is NOT what I want).

A sufficient test for me would be that size is always a constant (never a variable).

I would use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`, but I cannot figure out how to use it for what I need.

Comment: Here's another suggestion: Cease these puny microoptimization efforts and leave this to the compiler. It can do better anyway, and your code won't be littered with ugliness for no reason. And even if you compiler was from 1970 and didn't optimize this, odds are it still not needed/has absolutely no noticeable effect on performance!

Comment: what is the purpose of this? Surely any decent optimizer will optimize operations involving powers of two!?!

Comment: GCC with -O3 optimizes `var % constant` to exactly that if `constant` is a power of two. It is a pretty well known and simple to implement optimization, so I assume that other compilers will also do this.

Comment: At any rate (regarding my comment, @delnan's and @Nim's), while the manual micro-optimization might not be important, ensuring that the number is a power of 2 (so that the compiler can actually perform that optimization itself) is a valid goal. That is, while I would remove that macro, ensuring at compile time that `size` is a power of 2 is a sensible idea.

Comment: The LLVM Backend get it right (for 4), and even better, does not generate buggy code if `v` is (for some reason) signed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: that micro optimization is not needed. Any decent compiler with optimizations enabled will convert `a % b` into that construct when `b` is a compile time constant that is actually a power of 2.

Then on the particular assert, you can use the same construct to assert it [*]:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( !(size & (size-1)) );
```

[*] Note that as Matthieu M points out this only works if `size` is an unsigned type. And that should be asserted --the lesser requirement that the argument is non-negative cannot be asserted at compile time:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( (X(0)-1) > X(0) ); // where X is the type of the argument
```

EDIT after last comment:

You are missing the point here. For a static assertion macro to work, the `size` must be a compile time constant. If it is a compile time constant then just assert *when the constant is defined* which is also the best place, as it will serve as documentation, and will point to the precise point of code that needs modification:

```
template <typename N>
class hash_map {
public:
   const std::size_t size = N;
   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( !(size & (size-1) ) ); // N must be power of 2 for fast %
   //...
};
```

At the same time that asserting that the invariant is held at compile time is important for efficiency, obscuring the code is not: Just leave the modulo operation in place, as the compiler will optimize:

```
std::size_t hash_map::index_of( std::size_t hash ) const {
   return hash % size;
}
```

Because `size` is a compile time constant, and it is a power of two (you asserted that before) the optimizer will translate `%` into the optimized operation, while the code is still readable by humans that need to maintain it.

Comment: This will not handle size==0.

Comment: please also assert that the argument of operand is of an unsigned type.

Comment: This is what I think I want. So my macro should look like: do { BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( !(size & (size-1)) ); ((v) & (size -1)) } while(0); but then I cannot use it inside rvalue expressions. grrr.

Comment: @dbbd: You kind of missed the point, the static assert is required for the compiler to generate a fast modulo operation, but you do not need to manually implement it, leave that task to the compiler. Also, you do not need to assert before every use, it is a compile time constant, assert only at the place of call!

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Unless you have profiling proof that this is a bottleneck in your code AND that your compiler isn't optimizing thing like (v % 8) appropriately, just write the obvious code.

Otherwise since you're dealing with integers here can you use a template instead of a macro? Then you should be able to static assert inside the template so it'll flag when it's instantiated incorrectly.

For example something like:

```
template <int size>
int remainder(int v)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!(size & (size - 1)));

    return v & (size -1);
};
```

Comment: I agree in the *write obvious code*, but at the same time, the assert would be required for the compiler to translate the *obvious* into *efficient* modulo operations.

Comment: performing bitwise optimization on an `int`... arg!

Answer (score 3):

assert on:

```
size && (size & (size - 1) == 0)
```

EDIT: Explanation.

If size is a power of two, only one bit is set. Subtracting 1 will yield a value where all bits up to the original is set. ANDing these gives 0.

If size is *not* a power of two, at least two bits are set. Subtracting 1 will yield a value where all bits up to the original's lowest set bit is set. ANDing these will not yield 0, since the second and later (from right) bits are still set.

```
1000 & 0111 == 0000
1100 & 1011 == 1000
```

Comment: Look at David's answer for a smaller formula :)

Comment: A smaller formula because it doesn't handle size==0

Comment: @Erik: `0 & (0xFFFFFFFF)` yields `0`, which negated yields `true`, what is the issue ?

Comment: @Matthieu: 0 isn't a power of two, and 0 would be an invalid size within the OP's constraints.

Comment: @Erik: ah right... modulo `0` is likely to cause havoc. I'd prefer an explicit check for that case though (that is one assert for 0, because it's a strange value to come against in a modulo and so the logic is wrong, and one assert for the power of 2 issues, because it's simply a misuse of this function).

Comment: @Matthieu: maybe, but Erik has provided a pretty standard formula here to test "is power of 2" for integers. In this special case you can of course separately test "is this non-zero" and "is this non-zero integer a power of 2", but still this is the usual answer to the question posed. For that matter, you could argue for not handling 0 at all - `%0` results in undefined behavior, the programmer shouldn't feel *entitled* to a compiler warning ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I bite! (for that last sentence :p)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Only use this if size is a power of 2
#define REMAINDER(v, size) ((v) & (size -1))
```

Don't treat your users like idiots. Document your functions and macros, and move on.

---

Alternatively if you *really* must molly-coddle people, use a template:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
size_t remainder(size_t v) {
   // Perform whatever assertions you like on SIZE here

   return v & (SIZE - 1);
}
```

Note that I've had to make some assumptions about the type of input and output.

Comment: +1, I've restored parity, nothing wrong with the original or the edited answer...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but getting the compiler to enforce your own rules is *excellent* practice, not "molly-coddling". Compiler enforcement of an interface is probably the biggest reason C++ exists at all, and is always preferred to documentation or trusting developers.

Comment: @tenfour: Not for tiny little niggly micro-optimisations like this. Hello, code bloat!

Comment: If you see `y=8;...x=REMAINDER(y,3);` and later 8 must change to 9, you are unlikely to go read the comments for REMAINDER, and you will get a runtime bug. The real solution as we all agree is that he should just use `operator %` and forget about the macro (don't molly-coddle the compiler!). In the scenario you need a function which requires that an argument must be a power of 2, it's better to get the compiler to enforce, rather than silently allowing a runtime bug. "document your functions and move on" is dangerous; we should favor compiler interpretation over human interpretation.

Comment: Even "rename `REMAINDER` to `REMAINDER_FOR_POWERS_OF_2`" would be better advice than "just put a comment".

Comment: @tenfour: On the contrary. Training programmers to rely on defensive coding rather than training them to read the documentation for functions and macros that they use before using them, is dangerous. Remember what happened when IE6 let "web developers" take shortcuts with code to save them having to look up the more verbose specifics of, say, `document.getElementById`? We're stuck with horrid, bug-ridden code across the internet causing maintenance nightmares for all. There's no reason to think that the same thing does not apply in this domain.

Comment: Assuming the devs had the option of preventing that with a compile-time assert, are you saying it would be better to opt out, and let testers find the bug? Teaching devs by punishing end users doesn't work. If you would like to rely on documentation / comments above the compiler, why use types at all? Why use C++ at all over C?

Answer (score 1):

[Peephole Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization): Optimization performed on a very small set of instructions

This includes:

- [Constant Folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding): eg, here `size - 1` would be evaluated during compilation if `size` is constant
- [Strength Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction): which consists in replacing slow operations by faster ones... when the result is equivalent (obviously)

Now, let's see an example of this using the [LLVM backend optimizer](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi):

```
// C
int iremainder(int i) { return i % 4; }

unsigned uremainder(unsigned u) { return u % 4; }

// LLVM IR
define i32 @iremainder(i32 %i) nounwind readnone {
entry:
  %0 = srem i32 %i, 4                             ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  ret i32 %0
}

define i32 @uremainder(i32 %u) nounwind readnone {
entry:
  %0 = and i32 %u, 3                              ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  ret i32 %0
}
```

Let's analyze, would you ?

- `u / 4` yields `and i32 %u, 3` (which translated back in C gives `u & 3`)
- `i / 4` yields `srem i32 %i, 4` (which translated back in C gives `i % 4`)

What a **smart compiler**! It didn't forget that performing bitwise operations on signed integers would not yield the result I wanted (whenever the integer is negative, and branches are more expensive than divisions).

**Morale:** This kind of optimization is near useless, and you even got it wrong.

Comment: All of the answers that assume the use of optimization, are invalid due to that assumption. There are many reasons for not optimizing code, but this is a different topic.

Comment: +1 For bringing a part of the test that most of us (at least me) missed. Still, I think there are two different issues here: first at compile time asserting that the fast operation can be used, and then letting the compiler optimize for you. No matter how smart the compiler is, if you change the constant not to be a power of 2, then the optimizer will not be able to do anything.

Comment: @dbbd: I am not sure on what you mean with `assume the use of optimization`. If you are trying to say that you are not using the compiler optimizations, then the fastest optimization you can get is just adding the appropriate flags to the compiler call!

Comment: @David: I agree that this does not solve the compile-check issue. But my point was more than trying to outsmart the compiler (like many premature optimizations tend to) is rather futile. Anyway the compile-check has already been addressed in other answers :)